# Using VirtualBMC with VMs

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, bridge

I need to use one VM (master) to manage power status of another VM (slave) on the same host by `ipmitool`. I have installed `VirtualBMC` on the host machine, added the slave VM and started its BMC:

```
$ vbmc list
+--------------------+---------+---------+------+
| Domain name        | Status  | Address | Port |
+--------------------+---------+---------+------+
| slave              | running | ::      | 6230 |
+--------------------+---------+---------+------+
```

Both VMs are on the same virtual network with NAT enabled. No firewall on the host machine.

From the master VM, I tried to run:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -H <IP_of_physical_host> -U admin -P password -p 6230
```

But cannot reach the host machine:

```
Error: Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session
```

However, I am able to control the slave VM directly from the host machine with `ipmitool`. So I think something may be missing for my virtual network (bridge) setup on the host. Has anyone got ideas?

Environment: Ubuntu/KVM for the host machine. Virtual network created using virt-manager.

Comment: How is the VM networking set up? bridge or NAT?

Comment: Thank you, @dyasny. it is a NAT network. I was advised to use macvlan to address the issue, but I wonder if it is possible to somehow configure the virtual bridge to solve the problem.

Comment: The problem was solved after purging iptable rules. My mistake...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a bridge, your VMs and the host should be on the same network and you should be able to reach the host and contact vbmc. If you are using NAT, the host is listening on the `.1` IP by default (unless configured otherwise), so your typical address for vbmc would be `192.168.122.1:6230`.

You also need to make sure the host has the vbmc ports open in the firewall, of course. Otherwise, it's a very simple matter of hitting the host:port with the correct IPMI command, which vbmc will translate to a libvirt command, nothing else.

Comment: Thank you @dyasny. My mistake was in the iptable rule which blocked the traffic. But everything else worked exactly as you said. Thank you!